# Google Drive API : Do I need to submit declaration form for using OAuth 2.0 consent screen

Tags: android, upload, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am implementing backup and restore feature to Google Drive in my App which is going to be publish in Play Store. By using Google Drive we need OAuth Consent screen.
**I am confused about :**

1. Do I need to submit declaration form to Google for using Google Drive to read/write files of my App.
2. If I need to submit form, Just for Backup and Restore feature would google allow my request.. Any Idea based on your experience.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

You will need to submit a declaration form for Play Store publication if you use one of the restricted scopes listed on the [Permissions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9888170) help article.

Accessing Google Drive doesn't require this method of verification, however depending on which scopes your application uses, you will need to have your app verified independently as per the [OAuth API verification](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en) requirements (specifically if you use a restricted scope such as `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`.

#### Referenecs:

- [OAuth API verification FAQs - Google Cloud Platform Console Help](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914)
- [Declare permissions for your app - Play Console Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102?hl=en)
- [Permissions - Play Console Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9888170)